# How to create an SSIS Execute SQL Task Programatically?

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package programatically in vb.net version 4.0 for SQL server 2008 R2 and I am having difficulty creating an Execute SQL Task. The code for the task is as follows:

```
  Public Sub CreateExecuteSQLTask()
    Dim TaskHost =  DirectCast(Package.Executables.Add("Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ExecuteSQLTask.ExecuteSQLTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"), Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost) 
    TaskHost.Name = "Task"
    TaskHost.Description = "Task Description"
    Dim ExecuteSQLTask As Dts.Tasks.ExecuteSQLTask.ExecuteSQLTask
    ExecuteSQLTask = DirectCast(TaskHost.InnerObject, ExecuteSQLTask)
    ExecuteSQLTask.Connection = DestinationDBConnectionManager.ID
    ExecuteSQLTask.SqlStatementSource = "Select * from Employees"
  End Sub
```

When the above code runs I get the following exception when casting the TaskHost to an Execute SQL command.

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ExecuteSQLTask.ExecuteSQLTask'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

I have used the following article as a reference:

[Creating Packages in code](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Execute-SQL-Task-in-Code.aspx)

Please advise how I can get past this issue.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work out the problem.

```
Dim ExecuteSQLTask As Dts.Tasks.ExecuteSQLTask.ExecuteSQLTask
```

needs to be changed to

```
Dim ExecuteSQLTask As Dts.Tasks.ExecuteSQLTask.IExecuteSQLTask
```

As the exception suggested, the COM component can be cast to an interfaces. In the above case, i was casting the COM component to the ExecuteSQLTask class rather than the interface.

I found that casting the COM component is a lot easier than setting the SQL task's properties through XML.

Answer (score 0):

[Your problem is .Net 4.0.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/a85ec120-eec6-438d-aef4-55f82d14a869?prof=required) Or, more specifically, the ExecuteSQLTask assembly code has something in it that makes it incompatible with .Net 4.0. So just add the following lines to your app.config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
<runtime>
  <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

And it'll work. No, I have no idea why.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I had read an article that suggested this would resolve my problem, unfortunately it did not. I managed to solve this problem and have answered the question in this post.